# Error No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, excel, .net-3.5

With the below code when each match found I want to add the full excel row  that matches the criteria to `datagridview`

for example 
by passing the Row number 12 where the match found to a parameter within the query but I am getting an error message that says

the find works fine but it won't add anything to `datagridview`

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

```
private void B_General_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oWB;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currentFind = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range firstFind = null;

    string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DefaultDirectory + @"\new29.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";";

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TB_Search_Text.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("enter text for search");
        return;
    }

    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(DefaultDirectory + @"\new29.xlsx",   //---Filename OR FilePath
                             0,          //---object UpdateLinks
                             true,       //---object ReadOnly
                             missing,    //5//---object Format
                             "",         //---object Password
                             "",         //---object WriteResPassword
                             false,      //---object ReadOnlyRecommend
                             Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,     //---object Origin
                             "",         //---object Delimiter
                             true,       //---object Editable
                             false,      //---object Notify
                             0,          //---object Converter
                             true,       //---object AddToMru
                             false,      //---object Local
                             false);     //---object CorruptLoad;

    //loop to search witin all excel sheets (workbook)
    foreach (Excel.Worksheet SheetID in oWB.Worksheets)
    {
        Excel.Range oRng = oXL.get_Range("A1", "XFD1048576");

        currentFind = oRng.Find(TB_Search_Text.Text,
                                missing,
                                Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
                                Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                                Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                                Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
                                false,
                                missing,
                                missing);

        while (currentFind != null)
        {
            //Keep track of the first range you find.
            if (firstFind == null)
            {
                firstFind = currentFind;
            }
            else if (currentFind.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1) == firstFind.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1))
            {
                break;
            }

            currentFind = oRng.FindNext(currentFind);

                    string cmdtxt = @"SELECT * FROM [" + SheetID.Name + "$] WHERE R=R12";

                    MessageBox.Show(cmdtxt);

                    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
                    {
                        OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdtxt, conn);
                        conn.Open();

                        //da.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@rowid", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = "R12";

                        MessageBox.Show(cmdtxt);
                        DA.Fill(dt);
                        DGV_Data.DataSource = dt;
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

    oWB.Close(false, missing, missing);
    oWB = null;
    oXL.Quit();
}
```

I also tried this way

```
                    string cmdtxt = @"SELECT * FROM [" + SheetID.Name + "$] WHERE R=@rowid";

                    MessageBox.Show(cmdtxt);

                    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
                    {
                        OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdtxt,conn);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowid", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "R12";
                        DA.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        //conn.Open();

                        MessageBox.Show(cmdtxt);
                        DA.Fill(dt);
                        DGV_Data.DataSource = dt;
                        conn.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: @BugFinder at line  `DA.Fill(dt);`

Comment: because you dont use command you've made DA with cmdtxt, so to that you never add the parameter..

Comment: @BugFinder can you please explain more ?

Comment: @BugFinder I tried a lot before posting my question I have update my post now and set the value of parameter directly without using the command as you said. I am getting same error please if you wish to take a look